# Quadratic optimization with FFT

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, fast-fourier-transform, circulant-matrices

I'm trying to solve the following bounded quadratic optimization problem.

\begin{equation}
\min_{x}
\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textrm{s.t. }\\ x \geq 0
\end{equation}

Where $A$ and $b$ are block matrices given by:

\begin{equation*}
    A = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
        GD^{-1}(GD^{-1})^T & -GD^{-1}(GD^{-1})^T \\
        -GD^{-1}(GD^{-1})^T & GD^{-1}(GD^{-1})^T \\
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    b = \begin{bmatrix}
        GD^{-1}p \\
        c-GD^{-1}p \\
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation*}

$G \in \mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$ is a sparse matrix.

$D \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ is a circulant and symmetric matrix.

$p \in \mathbb{R^{n\times 1}}$ is a vector with elements all between $0$ and $1$.

$c \in \mathbb{R^{m\times 1}}$ is a vector consisting entirely of $1$'s.

$x \in \mathbb{R^{2m\times 1}}$ is the vector that i'm trying to find.

At the moment I'm solving this numerically, but it's extremely slow because $G$ and $D$ are large matrices. However, I'm sure I can exploit the fact that $D$ is symmetric and circulant by using fast Fourier transforms (FFT's) somehow. I can't figure out how.

-------------- EDIT -------------

I've just discovered that $A$ is positive definite and circulant and symmetric! This means I can rapidly calculate $Ax$ using FFTs. What algorithm can I use to exploit this feature?

Comment: A simplified version of this problem is to set $D$ as the identity matrix. If that is done, is there a way to make my QP problem solve faster?

Comment: How do you know this is convex?

Comment: I know A is positive definite

Comment: But you did not mention it

Comment: You haven't said what higher-level algorithm you're using to solve the nonnegative least squares problem.  Using an active set method will break the circulant structure of $A$.  Instead, try using a primal-dual interior point method- this will reduce the problem to solving a symmetric and positive definite system of equations involving $A$ to solve for $\Delta x$ in each iteration.  You can then use CG with fast $A$ matrix multiplications.

Comment: Thanks so much! Which interior point method are you referring to? Originally I was thinking of a barrier method. However, $A$ is so large that my computer can't store it without freezing. For this reason, I was thinking of using a projection gradient descent. What do you mean by $C$?